# Перехватить данные из поля и выполнить скрипт

Tags: php, wordpress

Ситуация такая: есть сайт на wordpress с плагином leads. В нём есть множество форм. Мне нужно вызывать функцию API "jivo_api.startCall('+14084987855')" при отправке формы и передавать номер из поля отправленной формы в эту функцию.

Как это можно сделать ? Обязательно ли редактировать каждую форму отдельно (проблема в том, что там нет такой возможности в админке)?

Comment: Приведите пример обработчика формы и укажите куда, как и после чего Вы пытались вставить Ваш вызов (на js надо полагать?)

Comment: Да дело в том, что это плагин Leads в WordPress. Я вообще не вижу обработчика...

Comment: Напишите свой обработчик дополнительно (в своем файле js), который при успешной отправке формы будет делать нужный Вам вызов API